# Function that reads integers and populates a 2d array with them

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

Need to write a program that reads a variable number of integers from different ifstream files then populate arrays with these integers. Some of the ifstream files have 5x5 arrays and some are 10x10.

sample ifstream file: 
rows = 5;   // rows
cols = 5;   // cols

1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1

Need to read all of these integers in and then populate 2d arrays with them. Trying to write a function that will use variables for the size of the dimensions and I'm not sure how to do it .

```
    void open_inFile(ifstream&);
    void read_data(ifstream&, int&, int&, int[][numCols], int[][numCols]);
    void calculate_array_results();
    void print_input_results(int&, int[][numCols], int[]][numCols]);
    void print_output_results();
    void print_decimal_values();
    void calculate_integer();
    int main()
     {
       ifstream inFile;
       //const int numRows = 10;
      //const int numCols = 10;
      int rows;
      int cols;
      int array1[][cols];
      int array2[][cols];


    void read_data(ifstream& inFile, int& rows, int& cols, int array1[][cols],x int array2[] 
    [cols])
    {
       while(inFile) // while ! EOF
     {
        infile >> rows; // get array # of rows
        infile >> cols; // get array # of cols
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
         for (col = 0; col < cols; col++)
           array1[row][col] = row+col;  // build grid
        inFile >> array1[row][col];  //populate
       infile.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');  // ignore blank line between arrays
       for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        array2[row][col] = row+col; // build grid
       infile >> array2[row][col]    // populate
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of the non-standard 2-d arrays you're using now (the reason why they are non-standard is that arrays cannot be declared with a variable number of entries).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie They can, in C (not in C++, though), but not *that* way. Nested functions are something werid as well...